# How to align label to the “BOTTOM” of a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am beginner to develop UI and i am trying to show Grid-view with same width and height as like below image and i want to set label at bottom of each grid items

I tried below code to do this requirement but its not working can some one help me please

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVWDENP91LF8

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: calc(25% - 4px);
    margin:2px;
    position:relative;
}

#bottom-lab {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Grid View</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 7</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
     <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 8</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 9</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 10</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @Vikas Jadhav you saw my code?

Comment: @AbhiRam, Remove `#bottom-lab` styles and I see it is already aligned without that piece of code. Also, id should be unique but you have used the same id `bottom-lab`

Comment: Can you please correct my code,Because i am learner

Comment: Always use `class` for `CSS` and `id` for scripts and others.

Comment: use class instead of id id="bottom-lab" and remove position absolute

Comment: @AbhiRam Check my answer below. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Id should be always unique and it just works below

- removed the `position:absolute`. Check for [positioning elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

> absolute - The element is positioned relative to its first positioned
>   (not static) ancestor element

- removed duplicate Ids `bottom-lab`
- Aded few CSS for a decent view

```css
* 
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column
{
  width: 150px
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(25% - 4px);
  margin:2px;
}

.column p, h2
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Grid View</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div>
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div>
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <div>
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div>
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div>
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div>
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 7</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
     <div>
    <h2>Column 8</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div>
    <h2>Column 9</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div>
    <h2>Column 10</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: width and height is not equal in your code and moreover i want to keep labels bottom of items

Comment: width and height are not equal?? It is applied from the class `.column` where width and height are specified as 150 and it must be the same. Also, what you term as label??

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your grid overlaps each other is because of the `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;`.

`position:absolute;` will not follow the flow of its container.
I tried commenting your `display` attribute.And here's the result:

**Also**, you cannot use the same id more than once. In this case, change it to class instead. Hope this helps.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: calc(25% - 4px);
    margin:2px;
    /* position:relative; */
}

.bottom-lab {
  /* position:absolute; */
  bottom:5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid View</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 7</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
     <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 8</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 9</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div class="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 10</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: width and height is not equal in your code and moreover i want to keep labels bottom of items

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the answer by adding jQuery script. Which gets the width and assign the same height to each div. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('.column').each(function(){
  var w = $(this).outerWidth();
  $(this).css('height',w);
});
```

```css
h2, p {margin:0px;padding: 0px;}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 17px);
  margin: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 250px;
}

#bottom-lab {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Grid View</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 7</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
     <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 8</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 9</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 10</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly but width and height must be same

Comment: This answer exactly i want but just little away from result Because width and height must be same

Comment: With some little jQuery we can do this too. let me update you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box. I love flex box. You can use the styles `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: flex-end;` on the grid item's class.

```css
.flex-c {
    display: inline-flex;
}
.flex-i {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-c">
    <div class="flex-i">text</div>
    <div class="flex-i">text</div>
    <div class="flex-i">text</div>
    <div class="flex-i">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet I hope you want this output.

```css
h2, p {margin:0px;padding: 0px;}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  
  margin: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 150px;
}

#bottom-lab {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid View</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 7</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
     <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 8</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 9</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
    <h2>Column 10</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be managed a lot easier with [CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/).

It was designed for this exact purpose.

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 150px);
  gap:10px
}
.column{
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding:10px;
}
.column p{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid View</h2>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 4</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 5</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 6</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 7</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 8</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 9</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <div id="bottom-lab">
      <h2>Column 10</h2>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with ID, an ID must be unique and you can't repeat the same ID. replace yours id=bottom-lab by class='bottom-lab' it will work better and ws3 friendly.